# rails has_one with multiple conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to create a has_one association whose conditon will have a inner query.

```
 class A < ActiveRecord::base
    has_one :table_b, :order => 'id ASC' :class_name => 'B' :conditions => ""
 end
```

Schema of table_b

```
table_b

id
name
```

Corresponding sql query I want to generate -

```
select * from table_b where name = "dummy" and id in (select * from table_b order by id limit 1)
```

Is it possible to write a condition which can execute this sql statement.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correct. I should add relation column in table_b = table_a_id (with type integer) then use scope, for example:

```
class ModelA < ActiveRecord::base 
  has_one :model_b, foreign_key: 'table_a_id', class_name:'ModelB'
end

class ModelB < ActiveRecord::base
  belongs_to :model_a
  scope :by_name, -> (name) { where(name: name) }
end
```

and Call like this

```
instance_a = ModelA.first 
instance_a.model_b.by_name('dummy')
```